# Hide title bar and show navigation bar in phonegap android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Phonegap Version: `4.1.1`

I want to show navigation bar and hide top title bar. How can I do that in phonegap. I am using phonegap build -- https://build.phonegap.com/

If I keep `fullscreen="true"` then it hides both title and navigation.
If I keep `fullscreen="false"` then it shows both title and navigation.

In earlier version when I user `fullscreen=true` it was showing the navigation bar and the title bar was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since the release of android@5.0.0, setting `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` in config.xml will use immersive mode, where available, even without this plugin.

You have to use a plugin like https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen and then:

```
// Extend your app underneath the status bar (Android 4.4+ only)
AndroidFullScreen.showUnderStatusBar(successFunction, errorFunction);
```

I hope this helps.